# .NET Framework 4.8 manifesto unknown

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to pull from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.5 but get the following output: manifesto for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.5 not found: manifest unknown.

I am new to docker and can't find this answer anywhere online. I've tried switching to a windows container and that didn't help.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by using the latest .NET Framework 4.8 version. I then had to switch to windows containers through the Docker App.